# Getting error "Thread 1: signal SIGABRT" after connecting outlets "datasource " and "delegate"

Tags: ios, swift

So I have been following a online Swift course and I am creating a table view. I almost copied all the code from the tutorial with only some adjustments (because the course is taught with a older version of swift but I am using swift 3). According to the tutorial  I should get a 4 row table view with names shown but what I got is a "signal SIGABRT" error. And the errors were not specifically pointed out.

what is wrong here? If I did not connect the "datasource" outlet I can run the simulator with no problems but I wont get the names shown. But if I do the connection I cannot even run the simulator. I really hope I have made the question clear and reader-friendly enough!

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate{

var cellContent = ["xiaohong","xiaohua", "xiaogang" ,"xiaoxiao"]

public override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
public  func tableView(_tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return cellContent.count
}
public  func tableView(_tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtindexPath indexPath:NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.default,reuseIdentifier:"Cell")
    cell.textLabel?.text = cellContent[indexPath.row]
    return cell    }
override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
}
```

In order to make it clearer I want to paste the whole error message here!

```
import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?


func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    return true
}

func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
    // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and invalidate graphics rendering callbacks. Games should use this method to pause the game.
}

func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
    // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
}

func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Called as part of the transition from the background to the active state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
}

func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
}

func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
}
}
```

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: If you could create a ZIP file of the project and host it on WeTransfer or some such service, I think it'd be easier to help you out.

Comment: it is on Wetransfer now and the link is https://wetransfer.com/downloads/b7321f3dadcd688228715bba053d159920170101114400/4a12c5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Swift 3 the signature of the method `cellForRowAtindexPath` is

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
```

see the space character after the underscore which is also required in `tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRows...`.

Further you are supposed to use reusable cells designed in Interface Builder

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
```

Answer (score 1):

The only problem that I can think of. Is that your tableview methods headers does not match the data source method headers:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    <#code#>
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    <#code#>
}
```

The problem in the cellForRow method. It doesnot match the DataSource method.

Answer (score 0):

I checked the project you posted on WeTransfer and there were several issues.

First of all, as hasan83 has mentioned, your method signatures are wrong. So the methods for UITableViewDataSource can not be found. This would cause a crash in itself. I recommend you use the autocomplete functionality in Xcode so you automatically get the correct method signatures. Just start typing `tableView` to get a list of tableView dataSource and delegate methods (provided your current class added these protocols).

Additionally, it seems you copied an attribute `@available(iOS 2.0, *)` from a header or something, this code should be removed as it is seen as a property.

The fixed project is [here](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/da00ddf7d43b41cb0e17006d11e4abda20170101115910/11a910dbd497b35994adeef407d0eed720170101115910/434a65).

Comment: Thanks so much for your help mate! appreciate it1